# On click change anchor text but not span

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the text of an anchor (`<a href=>`) on clicking an element.

The html structure is:

```
<h1>
  <a href="">
      change this text
      <span class="breadcrumb">Do not change this text</span>
  </a> 
</h1>
```

Jquery:

```
var clickedtext = 'Different Text for A href';
$('h1 a').not('span.breadcrumb').text(clickedtext);
```

But for some reason it removes everything under `<a href>` and put that text.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use nodes, you can assign the text directly.

```js
$("a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).contents().get(0).nodeValue = "new a href text"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a href="">change this text<span class="breadcrumb">Do not change this text</span></a> </h1>
```

Comment: That's a new thing for me. Let me try.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot mate. Learnt a new thing.

Comment: Done. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the element and append it later

```
var bread = $('h1 a').find('.breadcrumb').clone();
$('h1 a').text("cour text").append(bread);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save that span element in variable and then change text of `a` and append `span` back.

```js
var clickedtext = 'Different Text for A href. ';
var a = $("h1 a"), span = a.find('span')

a.click(function() {
  a.text(clickedtext).append(span)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a href="#">change this text. <span class="breadcrumb">Do not change this text</span></a> </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it :

```js
var clickedtext = 'Different Text for A href';
document.getElementById("toChange").innerText = clickedtext;
```

```html
<h1>
  <a href="">
    <span id="toChange">change this text</span>
    <span class="breadcrumb">Do not change this text</span>
  </a>
</h1>
```